# How to order posts by the user_login that corresponds to a meta_value (which is a user id)?

Tags: users, post-meta, order, sort, sql

I'm trying to create sortable column headers for a CPT list, but I'm stuck on one piece. When clicking on an "Assignee" column head, I want the list to display alphabetically by the login name of the user.

The following in `pre_get_posts` sorts by the user ID (saved as the meta_value via Advanced Custom Fields):

```
$query->set('meta_key', 'assignee' );
$query->set('orderby', 'meta_value' );
```

However, I'd like to order not by ID but the user_login it corresponds to.

I've successfully used code from this article (http://scribu.net/wordpress/sortable-taxonomy-columns.html) for taxonomy sorting (in a different column), but I can't figure out how to apply the same technique to the user table.

I've tried variations of something like the below in the `posts_orderby` filter, but I'm way off.

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(user_login ORDER BY user_login ASC)
        FROM $wpdb->users
        INNER JOIN $wpdb->postmeta ON $wpdb->postmeta.meta_value = ID
        INNER JOIN $wpdb->posts ON $wpdb->postmeta.post_id = $wpdb->posts.ID
        WHERE $wpdb->postmeta.meta_key = 'assignee'
        GROUP BY user_login
```

I really appreciate your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, solved this. I had to use the `posts_clauses`filter and the following code:

```
function assigned_to_orderby( $clauses, $wp_query ) {
    global $wpdb;

    $clauses['join'] .= "
    LEFT OUTER JOIN {$wpdb->postmeta} ON {$wpdb->posts}.ID={$wpdb->postmeta}.post_id
    LEFT OUTER JOIN {$wpdb->users} ON {$wpdb->users}.ID={$wpdb->postmeta}.meta_value
    ";

    $clauses['where'] .= " AND ({$wpdb->postmeta}.meta_key = 'assignee')";
    $clauses['groupby'] = "{$wpdb->postmeta}.post_id";
    $clauses['orderby']  = "GROUP_CONCAT({$wpdb->users}.user_login ORDER BY {$wpdb->users}.user_login ASC) ";
    $clauses['orderby'] .= ( 'DESC' == strtoupper( $_GET['order'] ) ) ? 'DESC' : 'ASC';

    return $clauses;
}
```

Adapted from http://scribu.net/wordpress/sortable-taxonomy-columns.html